# WMS and raster data

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I am calling in some WMS layers using OpenLayers. One of the layers is a raster. I have it working fine. But how does this fit into the spatial database model? I thought a WMS is a protocol for handling vector data. How raster data stored? Are they within PostGIS? Does GeoServer handle raster data?

Answer (score 4):

[WMS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms) is a protocol for displaying picture of maps. [WFS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs) is a protocol for sending vector data to a client while [WCS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wcs) is a protocol for sending rasters to a client. The key difference is what ends up with the client, if the client needs to work with the data then you want to use a WFS or WCS but for most web mapping projects a WMS is a fine way of sending a picture of your map to them, it doesn't matter if the underlying data is a raster or a vector.

GeoServer handles raster data by reading the data from a file in the data directory. Exactly where and how it is read from depends on the [data store](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/index.html) you are using.